# Do we have any control over dates when using native datepickers in html5 web apps?

Tags: html, datepicker, responsive-design

Here's the scenario..

I am building a responsive website, which will take bookings - and as such I will need to restrict the dates available (not too complex, simply disable a handful of dates a month).

I traditionally achieve this functionality with Jquery Datepicker, but when trying to create a smooth experience for mobile users - the native datepickers (eg iphone spinning wheels) provide a much nicer interface than Jquery Datepicker on the mobile platform.

So my question is, is there any way at all to manipulate the dates that are shown (like disable a specific date) **within native datepickers?**

If not, can anyone recommend a good cross browser datepicker as a fallback for mobile devices that doesn't weigh a tonne.

Answer (score 1):

sadly the native HTML5 `<input type="date"...>` doesn't support any formatting or restrictions. You are best sticking with jQuery or similar to control both styling and validation